# What does the following C macro do?

Tags: c

```
#ifndef INT64_C
#define INT64_C(c) (c ## LL)
#define UINT64_C(c) (c ## ULL)
#endif
```

What does ## mean in C? Is that a placeholder or function?

Comment: I recommend `The C Programming Language` Chapter 4 section 11, and you will know everything about macro usages in C

Comment: @Jens Consider `INT64_C(2+2) * 100` - here, to get the expected result 400, the parentheses are required

Comment: @anatolyg You're right, I didn't think of that. Good catch! Comment deleted.

Answer (score 10):

It is called the [token pasting operator](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html), it concatenates tokens so that `123313 ## LL` becomes `123313LL` during the preprocessing.

There is also a [stringification operator](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Traditional-macros.html) `#`, which converts `#name` into `"name"`.

Answer (score 4):

`##` means to concatenate two tokens.

So `(c ## LL)` will be pre-processed to `cLL`.

But pay attention, it's done in pre-processing stage so it's not like `strcat`.

```
int i = 3;
INT64_C(i);
```

will generate `iLL` instead of `3LL`.

Comment: two tokens, not two strings.

Answer (score 3):

No, `##` is not a placeholder for a function, it is a token pasting operator. It is valid only inside preprocessor macros (with or without parameters). It produces a concatenation of its left and right sides.

For example, if you pass `INT64_C` a value of `123`

```
INT64_C(123)
```

the result produced by the preprocessor would be equivalent to writing

```
123LL
```

The idea behind these macros is to make signed and unsigned constants stand out in the code a little more: a value that looks like `INT64_C(123)` may be a little more readable than the equivalent `123LL`. It is definitely a big improvement over its other equivalent `123ll`, which looks like a completely different number.

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned, `##` pastes two tokens together.

```
#define INT64_C(c) (c ## LL)
```

So, `INT64_C(123)` becomes `(123LL)` after macro expansion.

These macros exist so you can portably use `int64_t` constants.  On most 64-bit systems, the macro will be defined as such:

```
#define INT64_C(c) (c ## L)
```

This is because on most 64-bit systems, `int64_t` is `long` so the constant should be `123L`.  On most 32-bit systems and on Windows, `int64_t` is `long long` so the constant should be `123LL`.